# Fix Vimperator's "TypeError: elem is null" warning

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Vimperator often reports the error `TypeError: elem is null` (at the bottom status) when opening new pages. I cannot see that something failed, in fact, everythings works fine.

Is there a way to find out, what causes the problem? From an end-user perspective, everything works as expected, so is there an option to disable the warning? Pressing ESC hides the warning but it is annoying as it happens very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I see `TypeError: elem is null` message whenever I enter a command such as scrolling while a page is still loading, so that's probably what's happening.

Searching Vimperator `:help` for "error" provides no options for disabling error messages, so you might just have to put up with them (or wait for the page to load). (There are the `errorbells` and `visualbell` options, but they are `off` by default.)

Comment: You are right, scrolling while loading triggers the error. Now that there is way to reproduce the error, I guess I should file a bug report.

Comment: Bug ticket: https://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=866

Comment: A patch was submitted yesterday.